# cannot move a file into other folder

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to insert the content of few XML files into an Oracle DB and, after that, to move the files into an archive folder but it  fails on the movement step with error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Here is the code:

```
conn.Open()

For Each oFile As String In Directory.GetFiles("D:\files")

    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
    cmd.Connection = conn

    filename = New FileInfo(oFile).Name

            ' integrarea de delivery notes
            XML_File = XmlReader.Create(oFile, New XmlReaderSettings())
            DataSet.ReadXml(XML_File)

            cmd.CommandText = "pkg_erp.insert_delnote"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_delnote_id", OracleDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_order_id", OracleDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_product_id", OracleDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_quantity", OracleDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_confirm", OracleDbType.Int16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

            For i As Integer = 0 To DataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

                cmd.Parameters("p_delnote_id").Value = Convert.ToInt32(DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))
                cmd.Parameters("p_order_id").Value = Convert.ToInt32(DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1))
                cmd.Parameters("p_product_id").Value = Convert.ToInt32(DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2))
                cmd.Parameters("p_quantity").Value = Convert.ToInt32(DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3))

                temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                result = cmd.Parameters("p_confirm").Value.ToString()

                If result = "0" Then
                    file_waived = file_waived & New FileInfo(oFile).Name & Environment.NewLine
                Else
                    file_list = file_list & New FileInfo(oFile).Name & Environment.NewLine
                End If

            Next

            cmd.Parameters.Remove(cmd.Parameters.Add("p_delnote_id", OracleDbType.Int64))
            cmd.Parameters.Remove(cmd.Parameters.Add("p_order_id", OracleDbType.Int64))
            cmd.Parameters.Remove(cmd.Parameters.Add("p_product_id", OracleDbType.Int64))
            cmd.Parameters.Remove(cmd.Parameters.Add("p_quantity", OracleDbType.Int64))
            cmd.Parameters.Remove(cmd.Parameters.Add("p_confirm", OracleDbType.Int16))

            File.Move(oFile, "D:\archive_path_FullText\" & filename)


Next

conn.Close()
```

Can anyone tell me how to use the "File.Move()" in order to avoid the mentioned error message, please?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose these lines inside a using statement

```
' integrarea de delivery notes
Using XML_File = XmlReader.Create(oFile, New XmlReaderSettings())
    DataSet.ReadXml(XML_File)
End Using
```

This will ensure that the lock created by XmlReader on the file is closed and disposed immediately after the finish of the ReadXml method freeing the file to be moved in a different location

See MSDN [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)

The using statement is really important when you deal with disposable objects like files and **connections, commands, readers**. From your code it seems that you need to look also at how to fix the usage of these objects

Also you can move the creation of the command and all parameters outside the loop over the files, so you don't have to manually remove them and rebuild them again for the next file. Finally, do not build yourself a path string but use the provided Path.Combine method from System.IO namespace.

Comment: The "D:\files" folder may contain many file types. Besides delivery notes it can contains,  for example,  invoices or acknw.

For this, I generate the parameters inside the loop, after  I find out the  file type.

Comment: When I am using:  
  
`Using   
  
 XML_File = XmlReader.Create(oFile, New XmlReaderSettings())  
 DataSet.ReadXml(XML_File)  
  
End Using`  
  
it gaves me "Expression expected"  
  
when I am using  
  
`Using XML_File As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(oFile, New  XmlReaderSettings())  
 DataSet.ReadXml(XML_File)  
  
End Using`  
  
it gaves me  "Variable 'XML_File' hides a variable in an enclosing block.
"  
  
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should remove the declaration of XML_File. (_Dim Xml_File as Xml_Reader_